# Use the routes from the main engine in the mounted engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

are there any possible way that I can use the routes of the Main Engine from the Mounted Engine and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use method missing - like in [this post](http://candland.net/2012/04/17/rails-routes-used-in-an-isolated-engine/) or pass url through engine config like:

```
module YourEngine
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    config.some_route_url = this_url
  end
end
```